# Expose particular package from jar

Tags: java

Is it possible to access only few packages from jar file, and for remaining packages we can hide from them for accessing from jar file.

For instance,

[image]

I want to access classes from **p1** package  and hide all other classes of  **p2** and **p3** package
from jar file. While classes in **p2** and **p3** are public and are implemented in classes from **p1** package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some module system to reach this goal, eg.

- OSGi (current de-facto standard)
- NetBeans Module System (not very common outside NetBeans Platform applications)
- Jigsaw (upcoming standard module system in Java SE 9)

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible with default JAR file. You have two options:

- Mark private package as `internal` and document in such a way that client will not use, in document mention like "Classes under this package can change at any time" so clients won't use it, just like JDK does.
- Another option is to use `OSGi` which helps for your requirements. [More info here](http://www.modumind.com/2009/05/04/why-is-osgi-important/)